# How do I add a simple counter to a repeating action in apple script (script editor)

Tags: applescript

Basically I have a script that im running on my mac using script editor to prevent my character from be kicked due to AFK. Here is what I have right now.

```
delay 5
repeat 10000 times
    tell application "System Events"

        key down "w"
        delay (random number from 0.5 to 1)
        key up "w"

        key down "s"
        delay (random number from 0.5 to 1)
        key up "s"
        delay (random number from 20 to 30)
    end tell
end repeat
```

Basically I just want to add a counter so I can see how long it has been running. Ideally it would show the total time elapsed and not the amount of times the script has been repeated, but either would work.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways of counting (number of times the script was repeated and how long) involve using an accumulator variable.

Also, noting that `delay` operates in seconds, I converted to seconds for the `log` statement:

```
set numTimesRepeated to 0
set amountTimeRunning to 0

set delayValue to 5
delay delayValue
set amountTimeRunning to amountTimeRunning + delayValue

repeat 10000 times
    tell application "System Events"
        
        key down "w"
        set delayValue to (random number from 0.5 to 1)
        delay delayValue
        set amountTimeRunning to amountTimeRunning + delayValue
        key up "w"
        
        key down "s"
        set delayValue to (random number from 0.5 to 1)
        delay delayValue
        set amountTimeRunning to amountTimeRunning + delayValue
        key up "s"
        
        set delayValue to (random number from 20 to 30)
        delay delayValue
        set amountTimeRunning to amountTimeRunning + delayValue
        
    end tell

    set numTimesRepeated to numTimesRepeated + 1
end repeat

log "numTimesRepeated: " & numTimesRepeated
log "amountTimeRunning: " & (amountTimeRunning / 60) & " minutes"
```